# JavaToWs share types

Tags: c#, java, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a server in Java which has some `web-services`. **WSDLs** (and **XSDs**) are generated from java using **javatows** from apache cxf.

Some services share types, and I would like to share these types also in wsdl is it possible?

After that I want to generate *c#* code using **svcutils**, but because in each **WSDL** are some copies of the same types svcutil tell error that this complex type has already been declared...

I know that I can use /namespace switch but I do not want this because that way I will have the same classes generated in different namespaces... I would like to have one class in common namespace...

Comment: Can you post relevant part of WSDL or XSD which share these types?

Comment: Client side stub generation query was posted at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831390/svcutil-skip-complextype-of-a-wsdl-to-avoid-duplicates

Comment: I'd suggest splitting this question into two - one about CXF and javatows and the second about C#/svcutil

Comment: @Raghav I created small utility for myself which do just string comparision of generated code... I was not able to find better solution....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831390/svcutil-skip-complextype-of-a-wsdl-to-avoid-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a `common.xsd` file (if possible) containing the shared structures which are then included in each WSDL file for each one of the services.

```
<include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
```

I believe that will overcome the problems you're having when generating client proxy code with svcutil.exe.

Comment: well it is not possible because everything is automated, wsdl files and xsd are generated from java code... I am not doing it manually..